# Random order in Django

Tags: mongodb, django-models

I created my databases with mongodb, then I created a model in django and now I want order_by('?') order randomly, but the order does not change.

I am using django 1.4.1.

Thanks.

Comment: What package did you use to implement MongoDB support? Can you confirm that it supports random ordering?

Comment: Thanks @jathanism! how can I check it support random ordering?

Comment: I don't know, can you please answer the first question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB server (as at 2.2) does not have support for returning query results in random order.

One possible workaround, using a [Random Attribute](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/), is described in the MongoDB Cookbook.

Another less performant option would be to use a combination of count, skip, and limit with to find a random document.

You can vote or watch [SERVER-533](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-533) in the MongoDB issue tracker, which is a feature request for getting random items from a collection.  There is some further discussion on the Jira issue as well.